# Calculation arithmetic mean of object means

Tags: r, math, mean

I am trying to figure out how to solve this equation in R:

[arithmetic mean of object means K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txEEz.gif)

In a variable X is safe my data and append a column of the row means.

```
X$rowMeans <- rowMeans(X, na.rm = TRUE);
```

Calling X

```
V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 rowMeans
1  6  8  3   4   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.000000
2  6  9  4   9   5   6   9  10   8 7.333333
3  9  4 10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.666667
```

Because I need the number of NaNs and their position within the matrix X to calculate K I thought of a list. Somewhere on stackoverflow I found the following:

```
Counter <- 0
Result <- list(NULL)
Size <- 1
AddItemDoubling <- function(item){
    if( .GlobalEnv$Counter == .GlobalEnv$Size )
    {
        length(.GlobalEnv$Result) <- .GlobalEnv$Size <- .GlobalEnv$Size * 2
    }

    .GlobalEnv$Counter <- .GlobalEnv$Counter + 1

    .GlobalEnv$Result[[.GlobalEnv$Counter]] <- item
}
```

And added

```
for(i in 1:9){
    AddItemDoubling(which(!is.na(X[i])))
}
```

Calling Result

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 1 2

[[6]]
[1] 2

[[7]]
[1] 2

[[8]]
[1] 2

[[9]]
[1] 2

[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
NULL

[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
NULL

[[14]]
NULL

[[15]]
NULL

[[16]]
NULL
```

That looks great! I can use Result[4] to get

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2
```

Applying this to

```
sum(X$rowMeans[Result[i]])
```

gets me stuck due to the error message "invalid subscript type 'list'".

I am trying to get something like that

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
[1,] 6.666 6.666 6.666 6.166 6.166 7.333 7.333 7.333 7.333
```

Any help/hint is apprechiated!

Comment: alright, so I read again the specification of [R lists:](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list)

    `"In order to reference a list member directly, we have to use the double square bracket "[[]]" operator."`